# transparent popup window that doesnt take focus .net

Tags: c#, windows, timer, popup, transparent

I would like to create a Semi transparent popup window that simply appears at a location on the desktop for 3 seconds, it fades in and fades out but doesnt take any focus.

To do this I need to pass a string and fire up the popup in c#, similar to a jQuery popup but this popup must appear on the top most layer above every other window

Whats the correct approach?

Comment: If its transparent and doesnt take focus.. how will you ever know it was there?

Comment: @Sayse I think he means semi-transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is WinForms, then you'd just use a timer and the [opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx) property of the form. The form also has a TopMost property.

Answer (score 1):

As already noticed, Timer+Opacity for fade in/out

and override Form.CreateParams for get rid of focus. You shoud play with Style and ExtStyle properties of params to get exactly what you want. Here is an article with general explanation on this topic:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71808/Creating-a-Form-That-Doesn-t-Take-Focus